# Data extract from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data by uploading an Excel file. I am using Excel reader in my application which gets the stream and copies the data to the Data table. I need to know why I am getting `column0 column1` in the header of dataset when there is no header defined in Excel like that. Or how can I remove the header with `column 0` `column 1` `column 2` `column 4` etc. heading the first header in data set from the Excel file. I have added two images one is Excel and one is dataset which grabs Excel data but `column 0` `column 1` etc. are shown how to remove it.

```
Stream stream = file.InputStream;
IExcelDataReader reader = null;

if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
{
    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
}
else if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

DataSet dsresult = reader.AsDataSet();

string filedetails = path + fileName;
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filedetails);
if (fileinfo.Exists)
{
    fileinfo.Delete();
}


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dsresult.Tables[0];
dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[0]);
try
{
    var bl = new BusinessLayer();
    var data = bl.BatchInsert(dt);
    obj = new { resp = data, error = "" };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error(ex.Message);
    obj = new { resp = "", error = ex.Message.ToString() };
}

dt = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the first row is the header:

```
DataSet dsresult = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {
    ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {
        // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use a row from the 
        // data as column names.
        UseHeaderRow = true         
    }
});
```

Check the [Github page](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#asdataset-configuration-options)